# How do I get location of matched template in opencv?

Tags: python, opencv

I have this code so far.

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import pyautogui as pg

def grabscreen():
    i = pg.screenshot()
    return cv.cvtColor(np.array(i), cv.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

img_rgb = grabscreen()
img_gray = cv.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
template = cv.imread('capture.png',0)
w, h = template.shape[::-1]
res = cv.matchTemplate(img_gray,template,cv.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
threshold = 0.8
loc = np.where( res >= threshold)
```

It locates a template on your screen.
What the heck method, function, whatever would I use to get the xy where the template was found?
(Center of where it was found, like pyautogui does it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use minMaxLoc function to find the maximum and minimum values (as well as their positions) in a given array.

```
min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(result)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work. Can you provide a reproducible example with my code?

Comment: Use max_loc , that will give you the x,y coordinates.  https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2021/03/22/opencv-template-matching-cv2-matchtemplate/

Comment: "does not work" is not an actionable complaint. elaborate.

Comment: sorry. it does, I clearly was not trying hard enough